# stream.pipe expected but got process.nextTick(stream.resume)

Tags: node.js

As [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) are becoming more and more popular in node.js I'm trying to get a deep understanding of them. I looked at the code of popular modules like [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) and [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) and read through the [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).

There is still one thing that I don't understand. I sometimes see the following pattern:

main.js:

```
var module = require('./module')
module('something').pipe(process.stdout)
```

module.js:

```
var Stream = require('stream')

module.exports = function(string) {
  var stream = new Stream()
  stream.readable = true

  stream.resume = function() {
    stream.emit('data', string)
    stream.emit('end')
  }

  process.nextTick(stream.resume)

  return stream
}
```

I think this is really confusing because I would look for the `pipe` function inside the `module.js`. In the example I have to look for this one line `process.nextTick()` and then find the function that is called. As a beginner you might not know what `process.nextTick()` does and therefore have no chance to understand what the module does.

Is this pattern some sort of "best practice" for writing streaming modules? Why not implement the logic inside a `stream.pipe = function(dest){}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not totally clear on the issue you're raising, but the use of `process.nextTick()` in these cases is to allow the user of the module to add its `'data'`, etc. event handlers *after* the stream is created but *before* any events are emitted.  In your example `stream.pipe` isn't required, it's just being used as the stream's event handler in the client; that's why it isn't in `module.js`.

Comment: +1; it is necessary to be able to listen for `data` events from a stream *without* calling `pipe`.

Answer (score 2):

This is done to avoid firing 'data' events before subscribers (writable Streams you pipe into) have subscribed. This call to `stream.resume` kind of "gets the ball rolling" with your data. Incidentally, they are sorting out the Readable Stream bits to make it a little more intutive. You may want to follow over [here](https://npmjs.org/package/readable-stream).

EDIT: Incidentally, you should know that the call to `process.nextTick` means the function will get called on the next pass through node's event loop. That is how the deferred execution (which I agree is deceptive) is accomplished.